solana program deploy fails with "Error: XXX write transactions failed" on devnet
I tried to deploy solana program to devnet, but it shows error message like this.
Error: 41 write transactions failed

I tried to set flags like this.
solana program deploy ./path/to/file.so --max-sign-attempts 60 --with-compute-unit-price 53379 

I think that using public rpc url can lead to this error.
But then, without private rpc url, can't I deploy program to the network?

compiled .so file size is about 300KB. Can this big size be the cause of the problem?

When I tried to send transactions during non-congested times, the deployment was successful.
This seems to be due to a network congestion issue.
I've found that private RPC URLs are more favorable for deployment.
